# Searching items in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to get the items from DynamoDB table by querying against any attribute of the table except the primary key? In my table I have product ID as the Hash key and I have not specified any Range key. I want to add support for filters based on various attributes such as product price, product brand, available units in stock etc. And while filtering I do not want to provide the product ID since in most of the cases I may not know the product ID. Coming from a SQL background I was assuming DynamoDB to also have some sort of '**where**' clause to list records that match certain criteria/value of attribute(s). However, so far I haven't had success.

After going through the **Query** and **Scan** documentation also,I couldn't figure out how I can **optimally** use these operations to suit my needs. And how can I perform search/filter in my application without burning through my provisioned throughput capacity.

Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the attributes you want to query on. It will have its own capacity in both read and write units as well as [other considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html). If you need to add indices to an existing table, AWS preannounced [Online Indexing](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/) a couple months ago so look forward to hearing more news on when that is released. If you need more than just simple queries against these indices (EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN) you may want to consider using an search solution, such as [AWS Cloud Search](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/)